# PHP: Created File from exec() is always empty

Tags: php, linux, daemon, lampp

I would like to execute a command in **PHP** with `exec`.

If i pass the second param `$out` and start the script from the command line, it waits until the exec is finished.

But if I launch it from the Browser, the Browser immediately shows the result.

The command executes some unit tests and store the output in a file `($last)`, which I want to display in Browser.

Afterwards a logfile (`$logfile`) is created. Then the file from command will be formatted for html print with `nl2br()`.

I thought there were some permission problems with the user deamon, but if I give daemon the permissions for my project or the file on `/opt/lamp/htdocs/project` the created file is always empty.

```
exec($command , $out);

date = new DateTime();
$timestamp = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$filehandle = fopen($lastlog, 'r');
$filetext = fread($filehandle, filesize($lastlog));
$formattext = nl2br($filetext);

$last = file_put_contents($lastlog, $formattext);
$logfile = file_put_contents($projectdir . 'logs/' . $specfile . '/' . $timestamp . '.txt', $filetext);
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Is there anything written to the server's error log? Do you see any error message when configuring a more verbose error level?

Comment: If I use sleep(10) to wait for executing, it displays 'Warning: fread(): Length parameter must be greater than 0'

Comment: What's $command?  Probably either your web user has different access levels than your cmd line user or you haven't used a path to the binary that the web user can understand.

Comment: .....and what do you do with that warning?

Comment: I execute the script with cli, set permissions 777 to log folder execute with web user. No changes :/

@Devon: For every command I search with 'type -a command' and insert absolute path to command and every file. This happens too if I set user and group to myself in /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf